# Symfony2 translation cascading precedence

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation

How should I deal with common translations like this one?

```
send: Send
```

I need that word for the main bundle of my app (in src/), but also for other vendor bundles (in vendor/). I'm not sure how the precedence works, but it seems like the vendors take precedence. Eg: if SomeVendorBundle has this translation, it will be changed in my entire app:

```
send: Submit
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your translations with categories:

```
common.save: Save
common.created_at: Created at

user.created_at: Signed up at
```

Comment: But if there are no convention for this, collisions will still be possible. Adding a prefix like 'user.' only makes them a little less likely. I'm worried about not having any control over this. Every time I install or update a bundle, my translations could be changed silently.

Comment: By convention, third-party bundles should use a prefix based on a bundle's name. See how [FOSUserBundle does that](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml).